# Can the electrical signal in the Electromagnetic wave be rectified?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, electric-circuits, electronics, electrical-engineering, antennas

The radio waves are received through the antenna and in that case, we obtain the electric signal. Could that electric signal be rectified?

Comment: Isn't that what a simple crystal diode AM radio receiver does?

Comment: Would [electronics.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 1):

Yes they can and, as mentioned in a comment,  this is precisely how a [crystal radio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_radio) works.